# Consider a separable topological space $(X, \tau_1)$. Suppose that $\tau_1 \subset \tau_2$. Is the space $(X,\tau_2)$ separable?

Tags: general-topology

> Consider a separable topological space $(X, \tau_1)$. Suppose that $\tau_1 \subset \tau_2$. Is the space $(X,\tau_2)$ separable? What if we reverse the inclusion, that is $\tau_2 \subset \tau_1$?

The space $(X, \tau_1)$ is separable implies that there exists countable $D \subset X$ such that $D \cap  U \ne  \emptyset$ for all $U \in \tau_1\backslash\{\emptyset\}$. I think that this is a faulty statement since even if $U \in \tau_1 \implies U \in \tau_2$ there could be some $U' \in \tau_2\backslash\{\emptyset\}$ for which $D \cap U' = \emptyset$?

If $\tau_2$ is a subset of $\tau_1$ and for all $U \in \tau_1\backslash\{\emptyset\}$ we have that $D \cap U \ne \emptyset$, then in particular it should hold for all $V \in \tau_2\backslash\{\emptyset\}$ that $D \cap V \ne \emptyset$ meaning that $(X, \tau_2)$ is separable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, $\tau_2$ needs not to be separable just because it contains a separable sub topology. For instance on $\Bbb R$ the Euclidean topology is separable but the discrete is not (in general a discrete topological uncountable space can’t be separable). Now observe that the Euclidean topology is included in the discrete one.

Comment: Do you mean 'topological uncountable space can’t be separable' or 'topological uncountable discrete space can’t be separable'?

Comment: @geetha290krm fixed, thanks